# Capturing images from a camera in Python: easy, reliable, cross-platform

Tags: python, image

What is the most suitable way to capture a still image from Python and convert to a PIL image?

Google gives me numerous ways with OpenCV and lesser-known libraries. I want an easy, reliable, mature, cross-platform library for this purpose. And with minimal dependencies and extra packages.

---

If possible, it must also support [displaying live images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596960/any-quick-python-gui-to-display-live-images-from-camera) with major windowing toolkits, although the performance (frame rate, clarity) is not important.

Answer (score 0):

I use gphoto2 and with subprocess. But it should be possible to access this library from ctypes, if you prefer this.

Comment: I am sorry, gphoto is not available for ms-windows. But I guess it should be possible to port it.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV's Python API is pretty solid at this point, and OpenCV is easily installed on all major platforms. It's good, and it's probably your best bet. Getting a live feed from a webcam can be done in as little as 10 lines of code.

PIL or its newer fork Pillow are also good, mature, and cross platform.

PyGame also has a camera module, an intro is here: http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/camera/CameraIntro.html  but I have noticed that getting PyGame to integrate gracefully into other toolkits (wx, Qt) can be difficult.