# A wxpython widget that displays an image and returns the coordinates of a click

Tags: wxpython

I want a widget that displays an image and (can) call a function with the coordinates when clicked. I also want it to play nicely with being constrained by a horizontal box sizer.

What is a good widget for this purpose and the tutorial for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a live image feed and update it on a panel:

[Any quick Python GUI to display live images from Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596960/any-quick-python-gui-to-display-live-images-from-camera)

To get the coordinates of a mouse-over and clicks:

http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9877

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a tutorial that shows how to create a simple image viewer [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/). To get the coordinates of a mouse click, you'd need to catch EVT_LEFT_DOWN and then in the event handler do something like event.GetPosition() or event.GetX() and event.GetY()